# Passar variável entre janelas javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Estou a passar uma variável da janela "A" para a janela "B". Até aqui tudo bem. O problema começa quando na janela "B" tento aceder à variável quando a janela inicia. O valor passado não existe.
Ex o meu código.
**Janela "A"**

```
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            AnchorPane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/gescomp/iniciarProva.fxml").openStream());
            IniciarProvaController np = (IniciarProvaController) loader.getController();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("Inicio");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 550));
            stage.setResizable(false);
            np.id = 33;
            stage.show();
```

**Janela "B"**

```
 public int id;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
   System.out.println("<< " + id + " >>");
}
```

Deveria "imprimir" 33, mas não mostra nada.
Se colocar um botão e ao clicar mandar imprimir a variável já dá!

O que estou a fazer de errado?
Como posso corrigir o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você está definindo o controller no seu arquivo `fxml`, dessa forma o método `initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)` é evocado durante a chamada do método `load` da classe `FXMLLoader`. Ou seja, antes de você atribuir o valor a variável`id`. No seu caso, o que ocorre é isso:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
AnchorPane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/gescomp/iniciarProva.fxml")
                        .openStream());    //Aqui o método initialize já foi evocado
IniciarProvaController np = (IniciarProvaController) loader.getController();
//resto do código
np.id = 33; //Nada acontece
stage.show();
```

Para resolver isso, você deve remover a referência ao controller no seu arquivo FXML e definir o controller programaticamente. Exemplo:

Crie um construtor que receba um `int` na sua classe `IniciarProvaController`:

```
public class IniciarProvaController  implements Initializable {

    private int id;

    //O resto dos seus atributos

    public IniciarProvaController(int id) { 
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        System.out.println("<< " + id + " >>");
    }

    //O resto dos seus métodos
}
```

Defina o controller ao `fxml` dessa forma:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/gescomp/iniciarProva.fxml").openStream());
loader.setController(new IniciarProvaController(33));
Parent root = loader.load();;
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setTitle("Inicio");
stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 550));
stage.setResizable(false);
stage.show();
```

Comment: Obrigado Filipe, resolvido.